# C# DataGridView disappears in form running on another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, datagridview, invoke

I have problem with DatagridView in form, which is running on another thread from main form thread.

1. I create instance of new form, for ex. "newForm"
2. I run it on new thread: `new Thread(() => coldTestVerifyResult.ShowDialog()).Start();`
3. I update some control (label, textBox) by `newFrom.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate{ ... })` - it's OK!
4. I update dataGridView also by invoking with parameters,but this dataGridView isn't displayed (data, headers, borders, nothing...)

I will be grateful for any help. Thank's

Comment: _in form, which is running on another thread_ - Why? Just don't do that. It should never be necessary.

Comment: because I have to be able update controls of this new form from main form without freezing main form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not show the form in another thread. All the UI work and all the access to the cotnrols should be done in the UI (main) thread. The behaviour you observe is exactly because you displayed the form in a new thread.

Comment: but if I show it on main thread, main form freezes. My app has to be able to update controls of new form in realtime, not after I close newForm dialog

Comment: @user2087665 Just use `Show()` instead of `ShowDialog()`.

Comment: If i use Show, newForm disappears immediately after it is shown

Comment: @user2087665 Well, use `ShowDialog()` or `Application.Run(newForm)` just for the last form.

Comment: Yes, but then my main form freezes and continues after closing of newForm. Or what do you mean with "just for the last form"?

Comment: `this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                    {
                        newForm.Show();
                    }));`  It work's but again, datagridView disappears

Comment: @user2087665 Wait wait! I don't know the structures of your forms, and you have not mentioned them in your question, and your question was about something else! Can you elaborate it in another question?

Comment: I think that question is related with this :) and structure, I don't know how describe them otherwise then one is main and one is "functional dialog". In reaction on some event in main thread, I need to create newForm dialog, but dialog, which doesn't freeze main form because main form has to react to some other events and by them update controls properties of newForm dialog controls, for ex. mentioned problematic datagridView. All other controls are updated OK.

Comment: And after I update datagridView, dataSet is OK, but datagridView isn't displayed...

Comment: I found some solution with ordinary `newForm.ShowDialog()`, when my main form is communicating with newForm. Thank's for your ideas...